# I updated the version of my .NET CORE to 3.1, but I have errors regarding Signal R

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr

I updated the version of my project and I have SignalR installed. However I have a couple of errors here: 
This is what I have in my ConfigureServices that I think is might causing this error:

```
 services.AddRazorPages().AddMvcOptions(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false);
```

And then I have two errors in the Configure method: 
Regarding SIgnal R

```
app.UseSignalR(route =>
{
  route.MapHub<MyHub>(caminho);
});
```

and 
I've already tried using endpoints like this:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
  endpoints.MapRazorPages();
  endpoints.MapHub<ChatHub>(caminho);
});
```

and it still does not work. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

With using Endpoint Routing, you can try:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //...

    services.AddRazorPages();
    services.AddSignalR();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    //...

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        endpoints.MapHub<MyHub>("/myHub");
    });
}
```

If your app requires legacy IRouter support, you can try:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

    //...

    services.AddRazorPages().AddMvcOptions(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false); 
    services.AddSignalR();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{

    //...

    app.UseSignalR(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapHub<MyHub>("/myHub");
    });

    app.UseMvc();
}
```

For more information about migrating existing ASP.NET Core 2.x project to 3.x, please check this article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#use-mvc-without-endpoint-routing